# Wordpress WP_Query, in category_name but not in specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi have a category with children categories in it. i want to show almost all categories except for some..

This is pretty much what I want to achieve:

```
$slug1 = '1998';
$slug2 = '1999';
$slug3 = '2000';
$slug4 = '2001';
$slug5 = '2002';
$cat1 = get_category_by_slug($slug1);
$cat2 = get_category_by_slug($slug2);
$cat3 = get_category_by_slug($slug3);
$cat4 = get_category_by_slug($slug4);
$cat5 = get_category_by_slug($slug5);

$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
'orderby' => 'rand', 
'posts_per_page' => '1', 
'category_name' => 'idols',
'category__not_in' => -$cat1, -$cat2, -$cat3, -$cat4, -$cat5
 ) );
```

But won't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't `category__not_in` be an array, or possibly a comma-separated string?

Comment: Yeah, saw that and fixed the error... hehe... Tried some differents ways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the problem!

```
$slug1 = '1998';
$slug2 = '1999';
$slug3 = '2000';
$slug4 = '2001';
$slug5 = '2002';
$cat1 = get_category_by_slug($slug1);
$cat2 = get_category_by_slug($slug2);
$cat3 = get_category_by_slug($slug3);
$cat4 = get_category_by_slug($slug4);
$cat5 = get_category_by_slug($slug5);
$id1 = $cat1->term_id;
$id2 = $cat2->term_id;
$id3 = $cat3->term_id;
$id4 = $cat4->term_id;
$id5 = $cat5->term_id;


$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
'orderby' => 'rand', 
'posts_per_page' => '1', 
'category_name' => 'idols',
'category__not_in' => array($id1, $id2, $id3, $id4, $id5)
 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
category__not_in' => -$cat1, -$cat2, -$cat3, -$cat4, -$cat5
```

should be

```
category__not_in' => array(-$cat1, -$cat2, -$cat3, -$cat4, -$cat5)
```